# Extracting all data from a .dat file using Binary Access Read (Application Defined error 1004)

Tags: vba, extract, binaryfiles

Blockquote

have some files in the .dat format,these files contain some valuable information however they can be quite big, trying to open each file in notepad and extracting the information I need is not efficient at all, as it takes notepad a long time to open each file. I have come across this Binary Access Read function which apparently opens large files and allows you to read them very quickly.

```html
Sub ReadEntireFileAndPlaceOnWorksheet()
  Dim X As Long, FileNum As Long, TotalFile As String, FileName As String, Result As Variant, Lines() As String, rng As Range, i As Long, used As Range, MyFolder As String
  
  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Show
    MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
FileName = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.*")
Do While FileName <> ""
  FileName = Dir()
  FileNum = FreeFile
  Open FileName For Binary As #FileNum
    TotalFile = Space(LOF(FileNum))
    Get #FileNum, , TotalFile
  Close #FileNum
  Lines = Split(TotalFile, vbNewLine)
  ReDim Result(1 To UBound(Lines) + 1, 1 To 1)
    For X = 1 To UBound(Result)
    Result(X, 1) = "'" & Lines(X - 1)
  Next
  Set used = Sheet1.Cells(1, Sheet1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Columns
  Set rng = used.Offset(0, 1)
  rng.Resize(UBound(Result)) = Result
  Loop
  
End Sub
```

. The problem is essentially I have all I want so it can end there but if this is going to keep happening its not very practical, any ideas on a solution?

the result of the script is so:

```html
MDF     3.00    TGT 15.0
Time: 04:47:24 PM
Pre-trigger Time: 20[s]
Recording Duration: 00:01:39
Database: dpdtoolp
Experiment: __140910_RB
Workspace: 13
Devices: ETKC:1,THMM(25362),THMM(25361),ADMM(448),CalcDev
Program Description: Module_ivupd2
WP: _AWD_1
RP: _AWD
§@
98 okt
Data: 14E410_299
PU Off

=
E1æ?b¡ClYDZ0C
Eä>
?C­ÛêB
?C
"CÝåÆB
×#<Ø³½C`C”¯„D-+@‰<ÕCs•D.ÄB)—>"
​
```

Comment: How large is the file (how many lines)?  And what version of Excel?  Your code seems to work OK on a random text file on my machine.

Comment: The files can get upto 70MB or even higher, I have added the result in the question, this is only part of the result it continues to about 180 rows, the only text extracted is the text I need which is shown at the top, I am wondering if there is a way to specifically extract only that text by using some kind of find function on the string? Do you have any ideas, hope this made it clearer.

Comment: I will guess that the "line" on which it "breaks" is longer than the 32,767 character per cell limit.  Try declaring Result to something like `1 to ubound(Lines), 1 to 10` and split each line so that the contents does not exceed that maximum.  Or, if you are sure your text will be at the beginning of any line, leave it the way you have it, but do something like `Result(X, 1) = Left(Lines(X - 1),255)`

Comment: Thanks for the response Ron, I have tried both changes to no effect. It produces exactly the same results. I see what you are saying, is there maybe a way to use the entire row instead of single cell, that way it is not limited to the cell size, I tried to do it but somehow ended up pasting the result repeatedly in every column until excel crashed, and then it still gave the same error..really frustrating

Comment: There may be something in the file that is causing the error message.  Or you may be implementing my suggestion differently than I imagine.  You might also try prefixing the contents of each cell with a single quote mark.  This will show up in the formula bar, but not in the cell, and it will force Excel to treat the contents as text.  It may be that something is being treated as a formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after running some tests, I'm pretty certain that the problem is that there is a line in your file that is being interpreted as a formula, and that formula is invalid (bad syntax or other error).

I would modify your code as below:

```
For X = 1 To UBound(Result)
    Result(X, 1) = "'" & Lines(X - 1)
  Next
```

Note the single quote.

The single quote will force Excel to see the line as text, and not as a formula.

An alternative, probably faster, would be to format the destination range as text before writing the array.  `.numberformat = "@"`

You may also have a separate problem with too many characters in the cell, but that is easily corrected.

Comment: You my friend are an absolute genius!!! works perfectly the quotation mark did the trick!

Comment: HI sorry, I am trying to loop through all files in a folder, for some reason I am getting error subscript out of range 9 on line ReDim Result(1 To UBound(Lines) + 1, 1 To 1). I cant understand why its different all I have done is added a loop

Comment: It doesn't let me see but TotalFile= ""  seems to be empty, so I am guessing Lines is also empty?

Comment: it also says UBOUND lines is -1

Comment: Well, that explains your error.  You aren't reading anything in.

Comment: I don't understand why that would be as I am pointing it to the right folder, and saying "Do While FileName <> ""
  FileName = Dir()" so it should pick it up..unless I am missing something

Comment: I use the FileSystemObject to access files -- I find it simpler to understand.  But why don't you manually look at Filename, and see what's there?

Comment: Its kind of weird because when I step through the code it picks up the right file name, so its kind of weird why it doesn't like it when it has to go this way..The reason for not doing it manually is that I need to run this for many files, also it needs to be used by other people so its easier if a macro runs all rather than manually having to go step by step.

Comment: Is the file empty, perhaps?

Comment: @Samatar  Well, there's some problem in the code you are using to access the files, or the file itself might be empty.  The latter is easy to check, the former might be more difficult.

Comment: Cheers for all the help...I will spend some time troubleshooting and hopefully climb this last hurdle!

Comment: Hi again Ron, just a quick question regarding this solution, unfortunately because of the solution of adding ' to avoid excel recognising symbols as formula it means I now have a post processing task to delete the symbols from the cells. Unfortunately its quite hard to do so, Is there a way to run the script to only extract the valuable lines of text data?

Comment: @Samatar It usually is not necessary to remove the formatting code.  What is the circumstance under which it becomes an issue?  And yes, you can certainly test your line to see if it is meaningful, before or after you put it into the Result Array.

Comment: The 15 lines of data I am trying to extract as shown above are then placed in a final information sheet. The way I do this is a recognise the headers time:, rp:, wp: etc however the last line "PU OFF" can essentially be anything, in addition there could also be a 16th and 17th line of user comment depending on the file. So at the moment when I get this extra lines of symbols, it makes it extremely difficult to only extract the text I need. So I would think it would be best if I could somehowe only extract the useful data? if you have any ideas on how? thanks!

Comment: @Samatar What was unclear about my suggestion as to checking each line?

Comment: Hi Ron, the suggestion is very clear, I just would not know how? How would I check the string before pasting in excel?

Comment: @Samatar well, if a valid line might start with `Time:`, you would check to see if the starting characters of that line are `Time:`, and so forth.  You could use various functions (e.g `Left`, `Instr`) and/or logical operators (e.g: `Like`, `=`) or you could use Regular Expressions.

Comment: This is understandable,(I have attempted to do this but I am struggling on getting this in the right place for e.g. tried to use instr(lines(x)':') but seem to be putting it in the wrong place. I am asking a lot but I am really stuck here I appreciate your help. Where would this search go in on the code because I am pulling in the total file)  ,, just one bit remains then, the last line of user comment does not have a header and could be anything how would  I differentiate that text from the symbols?

Comment: @Samatar From what you post here, it seems your syntax is incorrect for Instr.  But `Lines(x)` should return a string of a single line, for you to test.  You have not provided sufficient information to differentiate text from symbols for the user comment line -- perhaps look for characters that are not what a user could type in?  I recommend you post a new question, where you can show the code you are using to test lines; sample data; actual and desired results; and then it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Hi Ron, I am bewildered as to how to use the instr function but as suggested I have added a more detailed question  hoefuly its easier to help me get a solution, cheers again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28491683/search-for-specific-strings-of-data-from-a-binary-dat-file-only-extract-text