# Search for specific strings of data from a binary .dat file, only extract text

Tags: string, vba, binary, extract

```html
Sub ReadEntireFileAndPlaceOnWorksheet()
    Dim X As Long, Ys As Long, FileNum As Long, TotalFile As String, FileName As String, Result() As String, Lines() As String, rng As Range, i As Long, used As Range, lc As Long
    
         FileName = "C:\Users\MEA\Documents\ELCM2\DUMMY_FILE.dat"
        FileNum = FreeFile
         Open FileName For Binary As #FileNum
        TotalFile = Space(LOF(FileNum))
        Get #FileNum, , TotalFile
        Close #FileNum
        Lines = Split(TotalFile, vbNewLine)
         Ys = 1
         lc = Sheet3.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For X = 1 To UBound(Lines)
            Ys = Ys + 1
            ReDim Preserve Result(1 To Ys)
            Result(Ys) = "'" & Lines(X - 1)
            Set used = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, lc + 1).End(xlUp).Rows
            Set rng = used.Offset(1, 0)
            rng.Value = Result(Ys)
         Next
         
End Sub
```

I am trying to find some data in a .dat (binary file). The data should look like this:

```
MiHo14.dat
MDF     3.00    TGT 15.0
Time: 06:40:29 PM
Recording Duration: 00:05:02
Database: DB
Experiment: Min Air take
Workspace: MINAIR
Devices: ETKC:1,ETKC:2
Program Description: 0delivupd2
Module_delivupd2
WP: _AWD_5
RP: _AWD
§@
Minimum intake - + revs - Downward gear ​
```

The code I have currently extracts all data from .dat file and places in Excel file looks like this:

```
MiHo14.dat
MDF     3.00    TGT 15.0
Time: 06:40:29 PM
Recording Duration: 00:05:02
Database: DB
Experiment: Min Air take
Workspace: MINAIR
Devices: ETKC:1,ETKC:2
Program Description: 0delivupd2
Module_delivupd2
WP: _AWD_5
RP: _AWD
§@
Minimum intake - + revs - Downward gear 
Bã|ŽA…@@,s~?
B{À¿…@@@Ý‚Iá 
Á<
"@²n¢”N@ÇÿÈÿj
Ð=“SØ•N@ÇÿÈÿj   
à¨. —N@ÇÿÈÿj
 8²œg˜N@ÇÿÈÿj
0NI,¯™N@ÈÿÈÿj
Ðä$öšN@ÈÿÈÿj
@Q›=œN@ÈÿÈÿj
ÐŸe…N@ÇÿÈÿj
 GàÍžN@ÇÿÈÿj"
etc....​
```

I need to know how to use instr function to extract the information by identifying lines that include ":", the other challenge is there is a final line in the data that is a user comment this user comment can basically be any text, I need to be able to extract it without extracting the whole file because as you can see there is a lot of symbols (gibberish) that comes with it.

Comment: Show in your post the code you have tried to identify qualifying lines.

Comment: I get a subscript out of range error, to explain my thinking I think what I am telling it to do is check if there is : present and if there is then to add this to the Result? am I right or is this completely incorrect?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Hi, sorry to bother you again! unfortunately none of the answers so far have resulted in successful resolution of this issue. I have however managed to track down a document detailing the binary file structure, unfortunately my grasp of this kind of thing is limited, however you may be able to pick up from this the location of the information if I could send you the PDF maybe you can advise on how to change the code to get the required info?

Comment: If you could post a link to the pdf, I could access it.  Equally if not  important would be a copy of the file that causes the subscript out of range error when you try to run it thru your routine.  You can put this on a public site, such as DropBox, or OneDrive, and post a link here.

Comment: https://app.box.com/s/qd4oxba6mr40itec5s7meeghhpjh7tjz is the link to the file, https://app.box.com/s/ftoqyw5ov9yeegfyhxb2n8edrn9xlmwi is the link to the PDF file. Just to give you an update I no longer have the subscript error, I have managed to overcome that the problem is I am still getting this additional garbage in the excel sheet which I do not need, My hope is that you can tell me how to specify to the macro to copy the lines for the HD/PR/TX blocks (section 3.4/3.5/3.6) of that pdf. cheers

Comment: Hi Ron, thanks a million! If you don't mind adding a small notation to understand the difference between what the first code did to this one? For future reference? I just had to change the way it added to the sheet apart from that was perfect!

Comment: The different codes were provided in response to different problems.The first code I provided solved the problem you presented at that time -- which was you were getting an error 1004 when reading in the files.  That's a very different problem than what you present now, which is that you really only want to extract certain lines in the file; hence the code is different.

Comment: I understand that, I mean with regards to the code above, you have made a new code, which I want to understand a bit better. If I am not mistaken you are first extracting the whole file into a string, from there you pull out the lines that do not include 0 which would indicate invalid lines. you then redim the string to only have the relevant lines? just so I know next time what I need to do. what does ReDim V(1 To COL.Count, 1 To 1)
For I = 1 To UBound(V)
    V(I, 1) = COL(I)
Next I actually do?

Comment: I would suggest reading through Chip Pearson's site re:[VBA Arrays and Worksheet Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx) and also read about the VBA Collection object. For the latter, I would check VBA Help, and also do a web search -- there is plenty on the Microsoft web site. The code collects the relevant lines into a Collection object, then writes the collection object into a 2D array which can then be directly written to the worksheet in a single step.  This is all explained in the reference material I cited.

Comment: Much appreciated! I shall definitely have a read,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you want to copy all the  HD/PR/TX blocks to get the output you are looking for.

Examining at your file, one difference I can see between valid and invalid data (from your perspective) is that the invalid data either does not end with CR-LF combination, or contains a null character.  If that characteristic is consistent throughout your files, you may be able to use it to advantage:

Below is the code I used, and the results.  You can modify the variables for your own routine and see if it works consistently.

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub ProcessDAT()
    Const sFN As String = "D:\Users\Ron\Desktop\DUMMY_FILE.dat"
    Const sEND As String = vbCrLf
    Dim S As String, COL As Collection, V As Variant, I As Long
    Dim R As Range

Open sFN For Binary Access Read As #1
S = Space(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , S
Close #1

V = Split(S, sEND)
Set COL = New Collection
For I = 0 To UBound(V)
    If InStr(V(I), Chr(0)) = 0 Then COL.Add V(I)
Next I

ReDim V(1 To COL.Count, 1 To 1)
For I = 1 To UBound(V)
    V(I, 1) = COL(I)
Next I

Set R = Range("a1").Resize(UBound(V))
R = V  
End Sub
```

---

### Results

```
Time: 11:47:42 AM
Recording Duration: 00:01:09
Database: Testproject
Experiment: Measurement_Dummy
Workspace: Workspace
Devices: ETKC:1
Program Description: LPOOPL14
WP: LPOOPL14d2_1
RP: LPOOPL14d2
§@
Dummy test data
```

Comment: Hi unfortunately the honeymoon period of this script has ended, It is now starting to again add a few lines of gibberish, I am trying to add this condition as you said, it either does NOT contain CR-LF or it contains a 0. I wanted to add, If InStr(V(I), Chr(0)) = 0 or inStr(V(I), Chr(CR-LF)) <> 0 Then COL.Add V(I), however I am pretty sure Chr is looking for a character not a 5 characters, how would I adapt this to use this solution so that it either looks for a 0 or makes sure there is not CR-LF ending?

Comment: @Samatar You are asking wrong question. Script already excludes those characters. You need to examine binary of file and understand why script fails. Or post copy of failing file as before.

Comment: that was infact a silly question, What I want to ask you is what I know is the information I need is as the document states: "Text (new line indicated by CR and LF; end of text indicated by 0)" at the moment it is identifying lines that start with CRLF and then checking if they contain a zero, is there a way to see if they end with a 0? This I guess would guarantee we only get the correct ones?

Comment: Just to note I tried to use if right$(V(I),1) =chr(0) then....however it does not work. In fact it only fills the sheet with the gibberish I am trying to avoid. I think I am misunderstanding something. It might be that the whole block of data ends when there is a 0 so instead of looking for a 0 at the end of each line, I should stop searching when 0 is found, which I guess is what it is doing already. I am really at a loss as to why it would not work.

Comment: @Samatar The code looks for segments that **end** with `CR-LF` and do not contain Chr(0). As I wrote, you need to examine the file to understand why it is failing. As you discovered, looking for segments that end with Chr(0) is not useful.

Comment: Hi Ron, I appreciate all your support! I am currently looking at the Binary file. Can you briefly explain where the CR-LF is shown? I can see that the lines are broken up by .... depicted by 0d,0a, doesn't that the 0d 0a in fact show the end of a line? I can not see any other significant differences between then. Btw when you say chr(0) I guess in the binary this is "00"? I am new to this and again appreciate your answers!

Comment: @Samatar And I would be happy to look at the file that is misbehaving.

Comment: Thanks Ron, I am going to really push myself the next day to see if I can crack it myself. If I cant I will be sure to ask for more support, but with your suggestion to look at the hex code it makes way more sense now! :) (enough sense I don't know yet ha!)

Comment: Hi, I have been working on improving the script and stumbled across a bigger issue, sometimes I have files as big as 400MB and the script crashes as it is trying to copy all of that data in excel. I would like to know how to go the actual information I need so the data above which from the PDF is in the TXBLOCK, PRBLOCK. However I can not figure out how to target those blocks with this script, any ideas?

Comment: @Samatar Please post link to a copy of the file that causes Excel to crash, so I can work with it.

Comment: @Samatar In examining closely the sample file you provided, it does not appear that the HDR block (or any other block), contains a pointer to the TXBLOCK located at 0x025B (dec 603) in the file.  I think I'm not understanding the file structure.

Comment: @Samatar Is it possible that DUMMY.DAT is not a valid MDF file?

Comment: Hi Ron, Thanks for the response. Unfortunately the file contains sensitive information that I can not send outside of the company. However I do think the Dummy file is correct although I removed some information in order to be able to sent it, this may have altered some things. Can you explain how to identify a location as you have just done with "0x025B" from the PDF file it tells me to look for HD and that it has a pointer to the TX and PR blocks? it says it has a link pointer to TX/PR Blocks. If you do maybe know I can use that information as it should always be in same place.

Comment: @Samatar Some LINKs are in the HDR block; and the format is described in the PDF document.  In the file DUMP in the PDF file, you can see that the LINKs point to the location of the blocks; but in your DUMMY.DAT file, they do not.  To find a location, I just looked at a TX block in the HEX dump in the DUMMY.DAT file and read the address.  But that address doesn't seem to exist in the DUMMY.DAT file.

Comment: @Samatar If the file crashes on trying to read the whole thing in, and the crash is not something correctible with your reading routine; and if you can't follow the LINKs to find the appropriate sections, scanning through the entire file looking for TX headers, and then reading in that block is one possibility, I suppose.  But that will take a long time.

Comment: OK I think we should assume that the Dummy file is not correctly structured. For a dummy as I am, how do you identify a location in HEX? So for e.g. if HD always starts at 0xA4? Also if we assume the link will work in the other files, how do I follow a link? So in short if we assume the PDF file information is how all the files will be set up. What I would like it to do is to find HD block follow the link to the TXBlock copy into a array and close the file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72535/discussion-between-ron-rosenfeld-and-samatar).

Comment: Hi Ron, (Please see answer I posted) after some studying I finally have it working, it works on all the files tested bar the dummy file. Now I want to know if I can make it more robust, at the moment I am running on the assumption my information doesn't exceed 1000, however do you know how I can utilise the size information given next to MLocation?

Answer (score 0):

That code won't compile because you haven't looped your for loop.

```
Sub ReadEntireFileAndPlaceOnWorksheet()
    Dim X As Long, Y As Long, FileNum As Long, sFile As String, FileName As String, Result() As String, Lines() As String, rng As Range, i As Long, used As Range, MyFolder As String

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Show
        MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    FileName = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.*")
    Do Until FileName = ""
        sFile = ReadFile(MyFolder & "\" & FileName)
        Lines = Split(sFile, vbLf)
        Y = 1
        For X = 1 To UBound(Lines)
            If InStr(1, Lines(X), ":", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
                ReDim Preserve Result(Y) '<-- Changed to a 1D array, I don't know why you had a 2D
                Result(Y) = "'" & Lines(X - 1)
                Y = Y + 1 '<-- increases to resize the array as it goes
            End If
        Next '<-- Added that in
        Set used = Sheet1.Cells(1, Sheet1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Columns
        Set rng = used.Offset(0, 1)
        rng.Resize(UBound(Result)).Formula = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Result))
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub


Function ReadFile(ByVal strFile As String) As String
On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    Dim FileNumber  As Integer
    Dim sFile       As String 'Variable contain file content
    FileNumber = FreeFile
    Open strFile For Binary Access Read As FileNumber
    sFile = Space(LOF(FileNumber))
    Get #FileNumber, , sFile
    Close FileNumber

    ReadFile = sFile

Error_Handler_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Function

Error_Handler:
    MsgBox "The following error has occured." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
            "Error Source: ReadFile" & vbCrLf & _
            "Error Description: " & Err.Description, _
            vbCritical, "An Error has Occured!"
    Resume Error_Handler_Exit
End Function
```

Changed your array to 1 dimension

Lastly, if you indent your code properly it makes it a lot easier to read and help you.

Credit here for the file reading: http://www.devhut.net/2012/05/14/vba-read-file-into-memory/

Comment: Sorry about the messy code, subscript error 9 still comes up on the line ReDim Preserve Result(Y)

Comment: You have several issues with `Result`: 1) it's Dim'd as fixed size.  Use `Dim Result() As String` (this causes the error) 2) specify the lower bound with `ReDim Preserve Result(1 To Y)` 3) the `For` loop won't work because `Result` isn't initialised at that time.  Use `For X = 0 To UBound(Lines)` (and adjust the indexes into `Lines`)

Comment: @chrisneilsen  Apologies, I did not understand your solution number 3. If I understand correctly you are saving the lines that have ":" in this result string correct?  If you don't mind showing it so I can run through line by line and make sense of it? Much appreciated

Comment: @Samatar sorry, wasn't that clear on point 3.  There were actually two issues there: firstly your logic really requires a loop over `Lines` anyway, so that change is needed regardless.  Secondly, when you declare a Dynamic Array (thats what it's called when you declare an array without a size) it starts out uninitialised.  if you try `UBound` on an uninitialised array you will get an Error 9 Subscript out of range.

Comment: @DanDonoghue only just spotted your change, firstly cheers, secondly it doesn't work Type mismatch error 13, on the transpose function, why do you need to transpose? Secondly if its not too much to ask similar to your first solution if you can explain a little bit what its doing, Im quite new to VBA and want to learn as I get the help! cheers again

Comment: @chrisneilsen Hi mate ive managed to confuse myself quite badly, first of all, if I am setting Y to 1 then saying ReDim Preserve Result(1 to Y) this surely cant be correct. Secondly the subscript out of range happens on Lines (X-1). Originally I understood that for X to Ubounc (lines( means from line 1 to the end of this string,InStr(1, Lines(X), ":", vbTextCompare) then out this line into the Result variant. this I could understand this new solution seems a bit over my head, Do you mind just annotating the original question to show my errors? if its not too much to ask

Comment: @chrisneilsen Sorry for the million comments but finally! I have it working now,using the code above, thanks to your answers I managed to work it out, unfortunately though it seems that ":" qualifier is not enough because it still brings in all the useless text I have, does excel or vba recognise actual sentences so that I can use some kind of if it doesn't make a sentence or if its only symbols then exclude from Result(Y)?

Answer (score 0):

```html
Option Explicit
Sub ProcessDAT()
    Const sFN As String = "C:\Users\Mohamed samatar.DSSE-EMEA\Documents\EQVL\Test\WHVP113_140827_TTinsug_TTbana_292Data_WOT_TakeOff_Launch_LaunchPlus_PUoff_REF_1.dat"
    Const sEND As String = vbCrLf
    Dim S As String, COL As Collection, V As Variant, I As Long
    Dim R As Range
    Dim MLocation  As Long
    Dim PRLocation As Long
    Dim Mstuff As String
    Dim MSize As Long
    Dim MSize1 As Integer
      
Open sFN For Binary Access Read As #1
    Get #1, &H49, MLocation

    MSize = MLocation + 2
   
    Get #1, MSize, MSize1
    'MsgBox Hex(MSize1)
    
   
    Mstuff = String$(MSize1, " ")
    Get #1, MLocation, Mstuff
Close #1

V = Split(Mstuff, sEND)
Set COL = New Collection
For I = 0 To UBound(V)
    If InStr(V(I), Chr(0)) = 0 Then COL.Add V(I)
Next I

ReDim V(1 To COL.Count, 1 To 1)
For I = 1 To UBound(V)
    V(I, 1) = COL(I)
Next I

Set R = Range("a1").Resize(UBound(V))
R = V
End Sub
```

I used the Integer as it is a 2 byte data type and now it works, can you just comment if this is what you were referring to as the solution?!

Comment: This is a binary file.  So read the text block location into a four element Byte array; process that to obtain the location of TXBLOCK; Read bytes 3 and 4 of the TXBLOCK into a 2 element Byte array; process that to get the size; then read the entire TXBLOCK (less four for the header and size bytes) into a string  that has the correct number of spaces (size of TX minus four).

Comment: Hi, So I have written it out as Size(4) As byte. However the size is in Little Endian format so it would need to show Size (3), Size(4) in that order so how would I write the Get statement is my question in order to use this to get size of the block...does my question make sense sorry I have tried numerous ways and seem to either add them together or combine them some other incorrect way.

Comment: Or it may be that there is a similar problem with your real data as there is with DUMMY.DAT.  There could be any number of issues, and, since this is company business that you cannot share, I cannot go further on this with you.  Perhaps you need to figure out a different approach than what I would use.  Perhaps there is a tool that would more easily read the file, than VBA/Excel

Comment: Finally I used the integer type to store the size information and now it works. Can you just comment if this is what you were referring to and if this is a robust way of working it? I use the Long type as it is a 4 byte data type to store the location of the TX block, this way it works.

Comment: So long as none of the text blocks have a size exceeding the maximum integer value, you might be OK.

Comment: Lets hope that is the case! Thanks for all the help, I have gained a lot!