# VBS Save File From Link

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I wonder whether someone can help me please.

I wanting to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662795/vba-or-formula-to-open-hyperlink-from-a-cell-and-save-rename-downloaded-file-f) solution in a script I'm trying to put together, but I'm a little unsure about how to make a change which needs to be made.

You'll see in the solution that the file type which is opened is a Excel and indeed it's saved as such. But I the files I'd like to open and save are a mixture of .docx and .dat (Used by Dragon software) files.

Could someone possible tell me please is there a way by which I can amend the code so it opens and saves the files in file types other than Excel workbooks.

The reason behind this question because I'm currently using a script which creates a list of files in a Excel spreadsheet from a given folder. For each file that is retrieved there is a hyperlink, which I'd like to add fucntionality to which enables the user to copy the file and save it to a location of their choice.

To help this is the code which I use to create the list of files.

```
Public Sub ListFilesInFolder(SourceFolder As Scripting.folder, IncludeSubfolders As Boolean)
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim fName As String
    On Error Resume Next

    For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
        ' display file properties
        Cells(iRow, 3).Formula = iRow - 12
        Cells(iRow, 4).Formula = FileItem.Name
        Cells(iRow, 5).Formula = FileItem.Path
        Cells(iRow, 6).Select
        Selection.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
        FileItem.Path, TextToDisplay:="Click Here to Open"
        iRow = iRow + 1 ' next row number

        With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    End With

For Each Cell In Range("C13:F" & LastRow) ''change range accordingly
    If Cell.Row Mod 2 = 1 Then ''highlights row 2,4,6 etc|= 0 highlights 1,3,5
        Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(232, 232, 232) ''color to preference
    Else
        Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(141, 180, 226) 'color to preference or remove
    End If
Next Cell

    Next FileItem


    If IncludeSubfolders Then
        For Each SubFolder In SourceFolder.SubFolders
            ListFilesInFolder SubFolder, True
        Next SubFolder
    End If
    Set FileItem = Nothing
    Set SourceFolder = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

Many thanks and kind regards

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Miguel provided a fantastic solution which on initial testing appeared to work 100%. But as you will see from the comments at the end of the post there were some issues when the user cancelled the operation, so I made another post at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29878297/vba-cancelled-save-de-activates-links) where the problems were ironed out. Many thanks and kind regards. Chris

Answer (score 1):

The code below shows how to retrieve the extension of a file, define an array with “allowed” extensions, and match the extension of the file to the array.

This is the outline for file manipulation, you'll just need to tailor it to you needs

```
Dim MinExtensionX
Dim Arr() As Variant
Dim lngLoc As Variant


'Retrieve extension of file

  MinExtensionX = Mid(MyFile.Name, InStrRev(MyFile.Name, ".") + 1)

  Arr = Array("xls", "xlsx", "docx", "dat") 'define which extensions you want to allow

On Error Resume Next

  lngLoc = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(MinExtensionX, Arr(), 0)

If Not IsEmpty(lngLoc) Then '

  'check which kind of extension you are working with and create proper obj manipulation 
  If MinExtensionX = "docx" then

     Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
     wApp.DisplayAlerts = False
     Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open (Filename:="C:\Documents\SomeWordTemplate.docx", ReadOnly:=True)

     'DO STUFF if it's an authorized file. Then Save file.

     With wDoc

          .ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Documents\NewWordDocumentFromTemplate.docx"

     End With

     wApp.DisplayAlerts = True

     End if
End If
```

For files .Dat its a bit more complex, specially if you need to open/process data from the file, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28422918/extracting-all-data-from-a-dat-file-using-binary-access-read-application-defin) might help you out.

Edit:

2: Comments added

Hi IRHM,

I think you want something like this:
'Worksheet_FollowHyperlink' is an on click event that occurs every time you click on an Hyperlink within a Worksheet, You can find more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838843.aspx)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

'disable events so the user doesn't see the codes selection
Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim FSO
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim sDFolder As String
    Dim thiswb As Workbook ', wb As Workbook

    'Define workbooks so we don't lose scope while selecting sFile(thisworkbook = workbook were the code is located).
    Set thiswb = thisworkbook
    'Set wb = ActiveWorkbook ' This line was commented out because we no longer need to cope with 2 excel workbooks open at the same time.

    'Target.Range.Value is the selection of the Hyperlink Path. Due to the address of the Hyperlink being "" we just assign the value to a 
    'temporary variable which is not used so the Click on event is still triggers
    temp = Target.Range.Value
    'Activate the wb, and attribute the File.Path located 1 column left of the Hyperlink/ActiveCell
    thiswb.Activate
    sFile = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column - 1).Value

    'Declare a variable as a FileDialog Object
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    'Create a FileDialog object as a File Picker dialog box.
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    'Allow only single selection on Folders
    fldr.AllowMultiSelect = False
    'Show Folder picker dialog box to user and wait for user action
    fldr.Show

    'add the end slash of the path selected in the dialog box for the copy operation
    sDFolder = fldr.SelectedItems(1) & "\"

    'FSO System object to copy the file
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    ' Copy File from (source = sFile), destination , (Overwrite True = replace file with the same name)
    FSO.CopyFile (sFile), sDFolder, True

    ' check if there's multiple excel workbooks open and close workbook that is not needed
    ' section commented out because the Hyperlinks no longer Open the selected file
    ' If Not thiswb.Name = wb.Name Then
    '     wb.Close
    ' End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

The above code Triggers when you click the Hyperlink and it promps a folder selection window.

You just need to paste the code into the Worksheet code. And you should be good to go.

Comment: Hi @Miguel_Ryu, thank you very much for this and my apologies for perhaps not making my situation clear.

I have a list of file paths in column E on my spreadsheet with a hyperlink in column F against each file which can either be a .docx or .dat. 

What I was hoping to do so upon clikcing the hyperlink is open up a dialog box allowing the user to save the file, so I was hoping to adapt this piece of code.

`Set wb = Workbooks.Open(hlink.Address)
    wb.SaveAs saveloc & hlink.Parent & ".xlsx"
    wb.Close True
    Set wb = Nothing`

Many thanks and kind Regards

Comment: Hi IRHM, do you need the file to be open and saved or just saved?

Comment: Hi @Miguel_Ryu thank you for coming back to me with this. I  don't need to open the file, I just need the file to save. If it helps I've posted the code in my original post which I use to create the list with the hyperlinks. Many thanks and kind regards. Chris

Comment: Hi IRHM, do you wanna try the Edit I put in, its not exacly what you were asking for but I think that's what you need . Miguel

Comment: Hi @Miguel_Ryu, this is brilliant, thank you very much. But could you tell me please is there a way by which I can stop the file from opening. It's just that some of files as I say are .dat files and are unablee to open in their own right, for example as a Word document would do. Many thanks and kind regards. Chris

Comment: Hi @IRHM, you are giving a File Path to the Hyperlink, if you replace  `Address:= FileItem.Path` with `Address:= ""` it should do the trick. Btw could you please put the answer as correct, perhaps even an upvote ;). Regards, Miguel

Comment: HI @Miguel, this works perfectly, thank you so much. Could I ask please, because I am keen to learn from this, if you could possibly add some comments to the code. Many thanks and kind Regards. Chris

Comment: Hi @IRHM, I've added the comments, and commented out some code that is not needed any more. Sorry for the low quality of the comments, they are not my strong suit ^^ If there's anything else I can help out with don't hesitate

Comment: Hi @Miguel, they're absoluely fine.Sincere thanks for all your help and Kind Regards. Chris

Comment: Hi Miguel I hope you are well and I wonder whether you could help me please. You kindly provided me with a solution as above, which unfortunately I've come up against a problem with. I extract the files to create the list and select the hyperlink to save the first file to the folder. However if I then go back to the list to select another file, the links no longer work and I'm not sure why. I just wondered whether you may have any ideas why. Could you possibly look at this please. Many thanks and kind regards.

Comment: Hi Chris, its working good for me. Does it prompt any error or something?

Comment: Hi @Miguel, thank you for coming back to me with this. That's the strange things, there are no errors thrown up. May I ask if it's not too much trouble that you post your file so I could use this as a base. I have a 'Drop Box' account which I could pick that up from if that helps. Many thanks and kind regards. Chris

Comment: A bit unorthodox but sure, fair warning thou, its the exact same code as above. Do the links work again after you save.close.open again the file?

Comment: Hi Migue, yes I appreciate your comment. I think I've found the scenario for when this happens, and it seems to be after the user clicks the link, then instead of choosing a folder to save the 'Cancels' the operation.

Comment: But no error? Try adding `On Error GoTo theend` at the top of your code and `Exit Sub
theend:
'` at the end, just before `End Sub`

Comment: Hi Miguel, the only error message I get is 'Invalid procedure call or argument'. But I think that may be the standard message? In terms of your last post. I get an syntax error for the last statement. Regards

Comment: `Exit Sub` and `theend:` have to be on different lines. But I couldn't tab in the comment ^^

Comment: Hi Miguel, thank you for this. Although the debug message now disapperas, I'm unbale to select any other link and save the file once this event has taken place.Regards

Comment: Did you close the Excel you are working on and Opened it again? Did you make any alterations to the code?

Comment: Hi yes if I cose the file, and re-open, the list automatically updates and I'm able to select the links again and I can confirm that I have not changed your code. Regards

Comment: Hi All, please see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29878297/vba-cancelled-save-de-activates-links) for the continuation of this post.