# Save file behind hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file that contains many Hyperlink who point to a word file on the server.

http://TITANUS/Fra/dif/avengers.docx

What I would like to do is to save content on my hard drive

[image]

Comment: That file isn't on the public internet.

Comment: no, it is on internal network

Comment: Do you want to do this with code? If not, just right-click and save link location, or double-click and then Ctrl + S.

Comment: We can't see your internal network; why did you provide the link?

Comment: i would like to  do it with code, there is more than 1000 files

Comment: Could you show us a [mcve] of the excel file?

Comment: done in the message

Comment: :-) Answer incoming. I haven't done VBA for months, so you'll have to tell me about any syntax errors.

Comment: Hmm... My VBA's too rusty to write an answer, unfortunately. [This question might help.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29691787/5223757).